# Import data from LATEST Google Sheet to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, google-drive-api

I have the same file name being saved into my Google Drive each day. Every file is in one folder, every filename is the same, every file is saved as a googlesheet but the data inside will be different and the modified date will be newer each day.

I'm looking for a way (I'll guess scripted) to import the data from the **latest** version of that filename into a GoogleSheet which I can then use to drive a datastudio dashboard.

Let's assume the Folder is called 'Exports Folder' and the daily file received will be called 'DailyExportFile'.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function lfunko() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folderid");
  const files = folder.getFilesByName("Filename");
  let fA = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    fA.push({ id: file.getId(), dv: file.getDateCreated() })
  }
  fA.sort((a, b) => {
    let vA = new Date(a.dv).valueOf();
    let vB = new Date(b.dv).valueOf();
    return vB-vA;
  });
  Logger.log(DriveApp.getFileById(fA[0].id).getBlob().getDataAsString());
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fA[0].id);
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  let vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}
```

Comment: Hi
I can get this running but no data is being imported into the target Google Sheet? Where in the code is it writing the data inside the target google sheet?

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine. I don't know where your target google sheet is so I just displayed the date in a Logger.log

Comment: If you can't modify this script to accomplish your needs that this is probably not the forum for you.  Some experience with Javascript is assumed.

Comment: With a bit of patience I got there in the end. Thanks